# Whether or not an extension is Galois over $\mathbb Q$

Tags: galois-theory

Is the extension $\mathbb Q(\sin\frac{2\pi}n)$ a Galois extension over $\mathbb Q$?

For the case when $n$ is divisible by $4$, I know that this happens. But I don't know how to do this in general. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some advanced perspective. The fundamental theorem of Galois theory states that intermediate fields $L/M/K$ (where $L/K$ is Galois) correspond to the subgroups $H\subseteq G_{L/K}$, and normal $H$s correspond to Galois $M/K$. Thus any intermediate extension of an abelian extension is Galois.

Since $\Bbb Q(e^{2\pi i/4n})$ contains $i=e^{\pi i/2}=(e^{2\pi i/4n})^n$ and $e^{2\pi i/n}=(e^{2\pi i/4n})^4$, it also contains the subfield $\Bbb Q(\sin\frac{2\pi}{n})$ because we can write $\sin\frac{2\pi}{n}=(e^{2\pi i/n}-e^{-2\pi i/n})/(2i)$. As $\Bbb Q(e^{2\pi i/4n})/\Bbb Q$ is abelian (with Galois group $(\Bbb Z/4n\Bbb Z)^\times$) we may conclude $\Bbb Q(\sin\frac{2\pi}{n})/\Bbb Q$ is Galois.

Comment: great solution. thanx a ton :)

Comment: What can we say about the degree?@whacka

Answer (score 1):

The field $$\mathbb Q(\exp(\tfrac{2\pi i}n)) $$ is Galois over $\mathbb Q$, for it is the splitting field of the $n$th cyclotomic polynomial. Your $\mathbb Q(\sin\frac{2\pi}{n})$ is the subfield that is fix under $z\mapsto \overline z$,

Comment: I think it's $\mathbb{Q}(\cos 2\pi/n)$ that's fixed by that involution.

Comment: The sine equals $\frac{\zeta-\bar{\zeta}}{2\color{Red}{i}}$ and $i$ needn't be in $\Bbb Q(\zeta)$. For instance $\sin(\frac{2\pi}{3})\not\in\Bbb Q(e^{2\pi i/3})$.